# Why does adding a parameter to DDO factory function break the app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I was under the impression (correctly, my Googling shows) that Javascript functions can take any amount of parameters, regardless of what's intended.

So it's strange that my directive works over here

```
...
module.directive('aye', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                replace: 'true',
                template: "<p> Hi </p>"
            };
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        {{ airportsArray() }}
    </div>
    <div aye></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but not over here

```
module.directive('aye', function(injectables){
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                replace: 'true',
                template: "<p> Hi </p>"
            };
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        {{ airportsArray() }}
    </div>
    <div aye></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am simply removing the parameter (which I found in [Angular's very own documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)) `injectables`. Why does this give me errors like

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=injectablesProvider%20%3C-%20injectables%20%3C-%20ayeDirective
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: In the documentattion, where it says injectables, it means your injectables, not literally the word injectables. Your code will work if you have for example, a service named injectables defined in your app. Does it make sense?

Comment: There is no service like `injectables`. The documentation just highlights that we can pass in dependencies in the directive definition function.

Answer (score 0):

Angular passes in these values via dependency injection. And determines what to inject based upon the name of the parameter (it can be more complicated when you get into minifying). And in your example above you have not identified a component (service/factory/value/etc) with the name "injectables" so the error it is showing you is that it can not find "injectables"

```
//Create something that can be injected:
module.service('fooService', function($http){
  /* ... some functions here ... */
});

//Inject this defined piece into your directive:
module.directive('myDirective', function(fooService){
});
```

When angular needs to create an instance of "myDirective" it will see that it needs the parameter "fooService" so it will go into its dependency resolver to find it then pass it in to your directive as a paramter.

Comment: Can you include an example of a good definition of `injectables`?

Comment: "injectables" is just a placeholder for parameters that can be injected by angular's dependency injection mechanism. That being said, I will put an example in my answer